# Does Server 2012 Essentials include some version of exchange?

Tags: essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I haven't had the time to install it and find out for myself and Microsoft is extremely vague about it.

Answer (score 3):

It does not. The following clip from [the Server 2012 Essentials blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/07/17/windows-server-2012-essentials-feature-list.aspx) sums it up:

> With Essentials 2012, there are three deployment options for messaging
>   and collaboration services for which we provide an integrated
>   management experience:
>
> On-Premises. Essentials 2012 contains integration with an on-premises
>   Exchange Server running on a second server, which can be either
>   physical or virtual.
>
> Office 365. Essentials 2012 builds on the previous Office 365
>   Integration Module for SBS 2011 Essentials. This option is now part of
>   the core product (no separate download is required) and it allows
>   customers that have an Office 365 account to use this service for
>   their email.
>
> Hosted Exchange. Hosted Exchange providers can offer add-ins to
>   Essentials 2012 that will allow customers to select this option. We
>   know that there are many different types of hosted email providers.
>   While we have focused on hosted Exchange email providers, we
>   engineered the product to be email service agnostic which allows
>   non‑Exchange based email providers to be integrated through this
>   mechanism (note that this specific feature is not available in the
>   beta).